# How client know which cookies should be send to the server

Tags: http, cookies, request, response

When I go to the HTTPS [server](http://rvvi.cz), I can see in Developer tools (or in Fiddler) a  **request cookies** that are send to the server by client. But how client know, which cookies should be sent, if no response cookies are sent by server. At least I can´t see any response cookies in Developer tools or Fiddler.

Answer (score 7):

First up each domain has its own cookies in a cookie jar / cookie store. Whenever a request is made by the browser to the server all cookies in the store for that domain or subdomain will be sent to the server.

**secure cookies vs insecure cookies**

Secure cookies will be sent only on connections that are made over ssl(https protocol). Normal cookies will be sent on both http and https protocols.

**session cookies vs. persistent cookies**

- session cookies - These cookies persist as long as the browser session is open. This means that Once you have cleared cache or closed the browser they get lost.
- persistent cookies - These will persist even if the browser is closed and opened again unless you have set the browser to clear cookies on exit in which case they will behave just like session cookies.

**First party cookies vs. Third party cookies**.

- First party cookies - generated by the domain currently open as main document - this means they have same domain as the one displayed in your browser.
- Third party cookies - generated by a different domain then currently opened by the browser(in the addressbar) but which are managed inside an iframe or various resource calls like css, script, media(images, videos or other embedded media)

**CORS** - cross domain calls via xhttp ajax calls - this case arises when you create a domain requests resources from another domain via xhttp(ajax calls). In this case the browser makes a preflight check to see if the receiving domain accepts queries from the origin domain(origin headers are sent to the domain to check the cross domain policy). The server must necessarily respond with a valid options header and the server may allow identity data which is short for cookie data. If the remote domain has answered correctly with an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header that allows your domain or "*" then you are allowed to send cookies via this request. And these will behave just like normal calls.

To read more about cors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I still don´t get how the browser know what cookies should be send :/ When browser want to access some domain/server, he send http request and server response header with cookie, isn't it?

Comment: The cookies are saved in the browser, the browser maintains a cookie file somewhere for each domain. Once a request to that domain is made the entire content of the cookie file is sent as cookies to the server. These cookies may have been generated by the server or by a javascript call. The cookies are not necessarily created by the previous response from the server.

Comment: Ahh,so there can be cookies made by JavaScript and in this case there is no cookie set in response by server?

Comment: Yes, cookies can be set by JavaScript too but they may have also been issued by a previous call, for instance most session id's are issued on login but they are always resent on each request even if the previous request did not issue them.

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer the question: the client sends back **all** cookie data it has for that **domain** and **path**.

If you do not see any `Set-Cookie` header in any HTTP response, it may be because the cookie has been issued by server and stored on your computer **before you started looking** at Dev Tools or Fiddler. It could have been up to a few days, weeks, even months ago.

In Firefox, if you navigate to `about:preferences#privacy` and click *Manage Data*, you can see which domains already have cookies issued and stored on your computer. The *Storage* tab in Firefox Dev Tools can show you details of all cookies. The expiry of the cookie is determined by the server, using the `Expires` or `Max-Age` directive in the `Set-Cookie` header.

**How a cookie first ended up on the client computer:**

1. Client makes its first ever HTTP request to server, e.g. `GET www.example.com`
2. Server creates a cookie and sends it back in the HTTP response, e.g. the response headers contains a line: `Set-Cookie: sessionID=1234567; path=/; Max-Age=31536000`
3. The client receives HTTP response and stores the cookie in the "jar" for domain  `www.example.com`.

**How server uses cookies to identify the client**

In subsequent HTTP requests to domain `www.example.com`, the client sends back all cookies in the jar that matches the path or sub-path. For example, the client wishes to issue a request `GET www.example.com/about`, sees that the URL is a sub-path of `/` in domain `www.example.com`, so it sends the cookie as a line in the HTTP request header, i.e. `Cookie: sessionID=1234567`.

The server sees the cookie and knows exactly which client made this request.